# Jump to the first occurrence of symbol in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I use the excellent [highlight-symbol.el](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el) to move between different occurrences of the same symbol.

[image: highlight-symbol-example]

In this screenshot, `foo_bar` is highlighted, and I can call `highlight-symbol-prev` to jump to it. Note that this is syntax-aware, so it's smart enough to know that `foo_bar_baz` is different (something isearch doesn't understand).

I'd really like to be able to jump to the *first* occurrence of a symbol. This would be brilliant for finding where symbols were imported. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should do what you want.

```
(defun goto-first-reference () 
  (interactive)
  (eval 
   `(progn
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward-regexp
       (rx symbol-start ,(thing-at-point 'symbol) symbol-end))
      (beginning-of-thing 'symbol))))
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about symbol-start within regexps. I'll post my solution, but yours is much cleaner.

Comment: Sort of - it has to get the symbol at point before moving to point-min.

Comment: If the eval feels too dirty you can let-bind the symbol-at-point and use rx-to-string. I felt it was less readable in this case. Maybe I'm too comfortable with quasi-quotes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
(require 'highlight-symbol)

(defmacro save-mark-ring (&rest body)
  "Save mark-ring; execute BODY; restore the old mark-ring."
  `(let ((old-mark-ring mark-ring))
    ,@body
    (setq mark-ring old-mark-ring)))

(defun highlight-symbol-jump-to-first ()
  "Jump to the first occurrence of the symbol at point."
  (interactive)
  (push-mark)
  (save-mark-ring
   (let (earliest-symbol-pos)
     (loop do
           (highlight-symbol-jump -1)
           (setq earliest-symbol-pos (point))
           while (< (point) earliest-symbol-pos)))))
```